# jQuery remove last element from array on back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Trying to remove the last element from an array when a back button is clicked. Console is showing the correct elements in the array. it's looking like the array.slice function isn't working however I can't see why.

Code is:

```
$('#backButton .back').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    answers.slice(0,-1);
    console.log(answers);
});
```

Answers array is showing the correct result apart from the last element in the array isn't being removed. Thanks!

Comment: `answers.splice(answers.length - 1, 1);`

Comment: That should work fine. Any error in the console?

Comment: No errors in the console - This solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **[`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)** method just returns the portion of an array it will not update the original array. You can use **[`splice(-1, 1)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)** or  **[`pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop)** method to remove the last element from array.

```
$('#backButton .back').click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     answers.pop();
     console.log(answers);
});
```

Comment: Will that only remove the last result from the array?